# Uninstall all changes made by Letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt

I installed Letsencrypt during the beta, following the instructions in the email, and now it seems broken on my debian jessie server.

I try to uninstall letsencrypt and want to start over with my (misconfigured apache)

---

What I did:

```
mkdir -p /backups
mv /etc/letsencrypt /backups/
cp -a /etc/apache2/sites-available /backups/
for i in /etc/apache2/sites-available/* ; do sed -i '/letsencrypt/d' $i; done
rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/*ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*ssl.conf
apache2ctl graceful
```

Is this enough? Or are there more files that would make a problem, when I start over again?

Comment: It will be very difficult, if not impossible, to discuss how to uninstall Letencrypt when you haven't told us how you installed it in the first place.  Maybe a link to the documentation that you followed might help?

Comment: I used this guide: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/quick-start-guide/1631

Comment: you may want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156009/how-to-uninstall-remove-certbot-lets-encrypt-from-debian-8